# Question about the approximation argument in the Logarithmic Sobolev inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am looking at the proof of the logarithmic Sobolev inequality (theorem 8.14) in the book Analysis of Lieb--Loss:

Suppose that $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and let $a>0$ be any number. Then

$$\dfrac{a^2}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert^2 \geq\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert f(x) \rvert^2 \ln \bigg(\dfrac{\lvert f(x) \rvert^2}{\lVert f \rVert_2^2} \bigg) dx + n(1+ \ln a)\lVert f \rVert_2^2.$$

I understand basically everything up to the approximation argument in the end. So we have proved this holds for $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R^n})\cap L^{2-\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^{2+\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Then they claim that the general inequality follows from a "standard approximation argument". Does this follow from the fact that

$$\overline{L^{2-\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^{2+\delta}(\mathbb{R}^n)} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)?$$

If it does, then I tried to use this explicitly and it doesn't really work out for me, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I also don't get the fact that  for $\varepsilon > 0$, we get that $\ln \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 < \lvert f(x)\rvert^{\varepsilon}$ and that this, together with Sobolev's inequality gives us that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lvert f(x)\rvert^2(\ln \lvert f \rvert^2)_+$$ is well defined and finite. This is all good of course, but how does this help us?

If you have any thoughts at all about this, I would be happy to hear them!

Comment: Approximate $f\in H^1$ by functions, say $f_k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $f_k\to f$ both in $H^1$ and pointwise a.e. (are you familiar with the fact that this is possible?), then use Fatou's lemma and the L-S inequality.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your answer! Yes, I was thinking about something along these lines. The general idea is pretty clear to me, but the exact procedure is not. For example, in order to approximate $f \in H^1$, may I use $f_k = f\chi_{\{k^{-1} \leq \lvert f \rvert \leq k\}}$?

Comment: No, because those functions are not necessarily in $H^1$ (Sobolev functions don't like jump discontinuities). One way is to regularize $f$ via convolution with a nice enough family of functions to get the $2+\delta$ condition, and then further multiply by a *smooth* cut-off function to get the $2-\delta$ one.

Comment: @Jose27 True… Well thanks, I’ll try it out!